# Недостаточно системных ресурсов при загрузке словаря

Tags: c#, devexpress, словари

Добавляю к spellchecker'у словарь:

```
        spellChecker1.Dictionaries.Clear();

        DevExpress.XtraSpellChecker.SpellCheckerOpenOfficeDictionary openOfficeDictionaryRussian = 
            new DevExpress.XtraSpellChecker.SpellCheckerOpenOfficeDictionary();
        openOfficeDictionaryRussian.DictionaryPath = @"Dictionaries\russian-aot.dic";
        openOfficeDictionaryRussian.GrammarPath = @"Dictionaries\russian-aot.aff";
        openOfficeDictionaryRussian.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU");
        spellChecker1.Dictionaries.Add(openOfficeDictionaryRussian);
```

Далее добавляю проверку орфографии

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        spellChecker1.SpellCheckMode = DevExpress.XtraSpellChecker.SpellCheckMode.AsYouType;
        spellChecker1.Check(memoEdit1);
    }
```

В результате при загрузке приложения и его попытке загрузить словарь получаю ошибку

> Additional information: Недостаточно системных ресурсов, чтобы загрузить словарь ru-RU.

Windows 10 Pro 1703, 16 ГБ ОЗУ
Проверка орфографии в Outlook и Word работает без проблем.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?